# Phonecall bot through the web

Tags: speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech-to-text, phone-call, telephony

So, I'm kind of lost about this topic and don't know if this is the best place to ask this but here is my problem to solve:

I made a STT (Speech-to-text) and TTS (Text-to-speech) bot so I can talk to my computer and ask him stuff, just like Siri. I want to make it more interesting connecting my bot to the cellphone/telephone line.

How could I make phonecalls from a linux system capable of listening in-real-time the voice stream and capable of "pushing" voice messages on the go?

I have everything already coded, I'm just lost how to "connect" it to the cellphone/telephone line.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a hardware question, but the answer is that you need an old device called a voice modem, and a land line phone.  At one time, these devices were common, when people mainly dialed up to connect to the internet.  A modem of this type is generally controlled by sending sequences of characters to an assigned serial port.  For example,

```
ATM2H1
```

would pick up the phone and turn on the speaker, which means that all the voice would come in through your audio mixer, as a sound like any other.  Or to call out,

```
ATDT15551234
```

where 5551234 is the hypothetical number.

If you decide to buy a modem, you can learn about the command set [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set)